# Horror movie about a haunted house that wasnt haunted at all woman was real

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I am looking for a horror movie I once saw, the problem is I only remember the end, which I googled myself silly for, but generally the ending is not mentioned (spoilers of course).

In the movie, a couple moves into a house, and see a woman, the woman keeps disappearing so they of course go right to "we have a ghost". But in the end, the woman crawls out of a kitchen cabinet and turns out to be an actual real woman. I believe she escaped from a mental institution or prison or something.

I think the woman that is part of the couple is pregnant or just had a baby, but I am not 100% sure if I am confusing it with another movie. I think she sees the woman several times on a baby monitor.

Its not an incredibly old movie, not from the 80's or so, but I am not sure about the release date. I think it is something quite recent (2010 to now maybe?), and I saw the movie two years ago I think.

Does anybody know which movie I am talking about. Google gets me nowhere, and I would really like to see it again!

Comment: not the movie you're looking for but this *actually happened*: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/newstopics/howaboutthat/2054057/Homeless-woman-comes-out-of-closet.html

Comment: also, the baby cam scene sounds like something from *Paranormal Activity*  so you might be mixing two movies together here.

Comment: I know it happend, but I truly saw a movie about it! I know paranormal activity has a similar scene. But it is nothing like that. In PA you never see an actual woman, just blackness and Kristie and Katie. And in the part I remember, there is clearly a woman on the nanny cam thingy, darkhaired, and of course they turn their head and then back, and she has dissappeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like [Dark Circles](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1863201/combined) from 2013.

> Haunted house film about a pair of sleep deprived parents who begin to experience disturbing visions after moving from the city to a country estate. Alex and Penny have just become parents of a baby boy when they decide that the city is no place to raise a child. Relocating to a farmhouse, the couple finds their relationship deteriorating due to the demands of caring for a newborn, including a lack of sleep. When Alex and Penny begin seeing a mysterious woman around the house, they at first dismiss the sightings as hallucinations brought on by sleep deprivation. But as the visions appear more often, the parents are forced to consider that evils are at work in their home. By the time the truth about their new home is revealed, their tenuous grip on sanity has already begun to slip.

The woman they keep seeing turns out to be a real woman who went insane after losing her baby. Here's the trailer (where you can see the baby monitor):

Comment: This movie sounds like the sort of "feel-good" film that'll make the winter evenings just fly by.

Comment: OMG, YES! Thats it! Thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you!!!!!!! Oh it was driving me completely nuts! Turns out what I thought was a seperate movie (about a couple not sleeping) is actually this movie too! So I basically found 2 movies I was searching for.... even though it was only one movie... THANK YOU!!!!!!

Comment: No problem. :) [@Richard Aw c'mon, at least that monkey costume's adorable!]